# Asymptotes of an implicit curve

Tags: calculus, projective-geometry

Per the method described at [How to find asymptotes of implicit function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474860/how-to-find-asymptotes-of-implicit-function/475304#475304) , I proceeded to find the asymptotes of
$$
x^3 + 3x^2y - 4y^3 - x + y + 3 = 0
$$

Whilst, it correctly generates the asymptote $$ y=x $$ , the remaining asymptote(s):-
 $$ 2y + x = ±1 $$ can't be deduced.

Instead another erroneous line $ y = 0 $ is outputted.

Some help will be appreciated.Alternate methods of solution would work too:)

Comment: The problem with the linked method seems to stem from the fact that $(X,Y,Z) = (2,-1,0)$ is a singular point of the homogenized curve.  I'm not familiar enough with projective coordinates to know how to get around this, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the slant asymptote exists, we may denote
$$k=\lim_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{y}{x}.$$

Then $$0=\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(1+3\cdot \frac{y}{x}-4 \cdot \frac{y^3}{x^3}-\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{y}{x^3}+\frac{3}{x^3}\right)=1+3k-4k^3=-(k-1)(2k+1)^2.$$

Thus,$$k=1,-\frac{1}{2}.$$

---

- If $k=1$, we denote $y=x+b$ and put it into the equation, we have $$-4b^3-12b^2x-9bx^2+b+3=0.$$

Then $$0=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{-4b^3-12b^2x-9bx^2+b+3}{x^2}=-9b.$$

Thus,$$b=0.$$

---

- If $k=-\dfrac{1}{2}$, we denote $y=-\dfrac{x}{2}+b$ and put it into the equation, we have $$-8b^3+12b^2x+2b-3x+6=0.$$

Then $$0=\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{-8b^3+12b^2x+2b-3x+6}{x}=12b^2-3.$$

Thus, $$b=\pm \frac{1}{2}.$$

---

As a result, the slant asymptotes are  $$y=x, y=-\frac{x}{2}\pm \frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: best approach is to combine *David K* answer(+1) (to find the inclinations) with yours (+1)( to find the intercepts).

Answer (score 2):

The question does not give details about how to apply the method of [How to find asymptotes of implicit function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474860/how-to-find-asymptotes-of-implicit-function/475304),
to this particular problem.
Here is an application of that method:

In homogeneous coordinates $(X:Y:Z)$,
where $(x,y)$ corresponds to $(x:y:1),$ the equation is
$$
X^3 + 3X^2Y - 4Y^3 - XZ^2 + YZ^2 + 3Z^3 = 0. \tag1
$$

On the line at infinity, $Z = 0,$ yielding
$$ X^3 + 3X^2Y - 4Y^3 = 0, $$
which factors to
$$ (X - Y) (X + 2 Y)^2 = 0.$$
This is solved by $X = Y$ or $X = -2Y,$
which says that the asymptotes are of the form $x = y + \text{constant}$
or $x = -2y + \text{constant},$ but this does not say what the constants are.

Continuing with the method of [How to find asymptotes of implicit function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474860/how-to-find-asymptotes-of-implicit-function/475304),
the derivative of the left-hand side of Equation $(1)$ is
$$
(3X^2 + 6XY - Z^2)dX + (3X^2 - 12Y^2 + Z^2)dY + (2YZ - 2XZ + 9Z^2) dZ.\tag2
$$

Evaluating $(2)$ at $(X:Y:Z) = (1 : 1 : 0)$ produces
$  9 dX - 9 dY + 0dZ, $
from which we eventually find the asymptote $x = y$ (whose constant term is zero).

But evaluating $(2)$ at $(X:Y:Z) = (-2 : 1 : 0)$ gives only
$0 dX + 0 dY + 0 dZ,$ from which we cannot derive the equation of a line.
(It is not clear how you got $y = 0$.)
So we have to find the constants that give the asymptote lines some other way.

Answer (score 1):

Giving

$$
f(x,y) = x^3 + 3 x^2 y - 4 y^3 - x + y - 3 = 0
$$

the asymptotic directions can be explored by substituting $ y = a x + b\;\; $ into $f(x,y)$ giving

$$
f(x,ax+b) = 3 x^2 (a x+b)-4 (a x+b)^3+a x+b+x^3-x-3 = (1+3a-4a^3)x^3+3b(1-4a^2)x^2 +(a(1-12b^2)-1)x+b(1-4b^2)-3
$$

Now the conditions for  $f(x,ax+b)$ to have line behavior are

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 3 b-12 a^2 b=0 \\
 -4 a^3+3 a+1=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

and solving we find two solutions:

$$
\{a =-\frac 12, \forall b\} \cup \{a = 1, b = 0\}
$$

so we have

$$
L_1\to y = x\\
L_2\to y = -\frac x2 + b
$$

Considering $f(x,y)$ at their asymptotic values it's value should be the same or

$$
\lim_{x\to 0}f(x,-\frac 12 x+b)=\lim_{x\to 0}f(x,x) = -3
$$

so this can be solved by choosing $b$ such that $1-4b^2 = 0\;\;$ giving

$$
L_1\to y = x\\
L_2\to y = -\frac x2 \pm\frac 12
$$

Attached a plot showing in blue $f(x,y) = 0$ and in red $L_1, L_2$

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but a couple of doubts.....Firstly, when we solve the first equation that outputs a = +1/2 & -1/2 and/or b = 0.Similarly,the second equation leads to a = -1/2 and 1.....How are we rejecting a=1/2.....And,why shall b be calculated by choosing (1-4b^2)=0

Comment: Also,how are we tallying the a's and b's....?

Comment: $f(a,ax+b) = c_1 + c_2x+c_3x^2+c_4x^3$ so the conditions are $c_3=c_4=0$. The value $a = -\frac 12$ obeys simultaneously $c_1=c_2=0$ and $a = \frac 12$ does not.

Comment: I guess that the last line of your comment has a typo as to the subscripts of (c).....At any case, how are we accepting that (a)=1, given that it does not satisfy both the equations, simultaneously?.......I think some more clarity on <1> the exact outputs of (a) and (b), per equation,<2> as to why a particular value of (a) is being rejected, <3>how are you tallying the (a)s with (b)s i.e. how are you choosing (a) as 1 and (b) as 0 in the same equation rather than (a) as -1/2 and (b) as 0, and <4> finally as to why you chose (1-4b^2)=0 ........would be immensely helpful.

Comment: @WingedBladesofGodric Yes. There is a typo. Should be $c_3=c_4=0$ I will try to clarify your doubts ASAP.  Just now I can't follow. Thanks.

Comment: @WingedBladesofGodric I added some explanations I hope will help.

Answer (score 0):

In other answers we find various heuristics leading to the conjecture that there are asymptotes of the form $$y= x+C\ , \qquad y=-{1\over2}x +C\ .$$
Therefore  we introduce new coordinates $(u,v)$ in the plane such that their directions become the directions of the axes:
$$\left\{\eqalign{ u&=x+2y\cr v&=x-y\cr}\right.\qquad{\rm resp.}\qquad\left\{\eqalign{x&={u+2v\over3}\cr y&={u-v\over3}\cr}\right.\ .\tag{1}$$
The given function then appears as
$$g(u,v)=f\left({u+2v\over3},{u-v\over3}\right)=3+(u^2-1)v\ .$$
The equation $g(u,v)=0$  is equivalent with
$$v={3\over 1-u^2}\ .$$
In terms of $u$ and $v$ we therefore have the two vertical asymptotes $u=\pm1$ and the horizontal asymptote $v=0$. These can now be expressed again in terms of $x$ and $y$, using $(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^3 + 3x^2y - 4y^3 - x + y + 3 = 0 \tag 1$$
Another variant of method consists in expending $y(x)$ to series of the form :
$$y(x)\simeq ax+b+\frac{c}{x}+\frac{d}{x^2}+... \tag 2$$
Putting it into Eq.$(1)$ transforms it to the form :
$$Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D+...\simeq 0 \quad\text{which implies}\quad A=B=C=D=…=0$$
where 
$$A=1+3a-4a^3=0$$
$$B=3b-12ba^2=0$$
Etc. But we don't compute immediately $C$ , $D$ , … in the general case because this will be much simpler latter in each particular case.

The roots of $1+3a-4a^2=0=(1-a)(1+2a)$ are $a=1$ and $a=-\frac12$.

Case $a=1$ :

In this case $B=3b-12ba^2=0$ implies $b=0$, thus $y(x)\simeq x+\frac{c}{x}+\frac{d}{x^2}+...$ Putting it into Eq.$(1)$ leads to :
$$C=-9c=0\quad\text{thus}\quad c=0$$
$$D=3-9d=0\quad\text{thus}\quad d=\frac13$$
$$y(x)\simeq x+\frac{1}{3x}+...$$
So, for $x\to\infty\quad \textbf{the straight line} \quad y=x\quad\textbf{is an asymptote.}$

Case $a=-\frac12$ :

In this case $B=3b-12ba^2=0$ is satisfied any $b$, thus $y(x)\simeq -\frac12x+b+\frac{c}{x}+...$ Putting it into Eq.$(1)$ leads to :
$$C=6b^2-\frac32 x=0 \quad\text{thus}\quad b=\pm\frac12$$
$$D=3-4b^3+12bc+b=0\quad\text{thus}\quad c=\frac{4b^3-b-3}{12b}$$

Case $a=-\frac12$ and $b=\frac12$ then $c=-\frac12$ :
$$y(x)\simeq -\frac12x+\frac12-\frac{1}{2x}+...$$
So, for $x\to\infty\quad \textbf{the straight line} \quad y=-\frac12x+\frac12\quad\textbf{is an asymptote.}$

Case $a=-\frac12$ and $b=-\frac12$ then $c=\frac12$ :
$$y(x)\simeq -\frac12x-\frac12+\frac{1}{2x}+...$$
So, for $x\to\infty\quad \textbf{the straight line} \quad y=-\frac12x-\frac12\quad\textbf{is an asymptote.}$

Comment: This seems quite nice and the best of the lot,without meaning any disrespect for the other answers......At any case, any hints about the expansion of y(x)?

Comment: At first sight, it appear nice considering the simplicity of the principle. But is is far to be the method requiring a minimum of work : very simple calculus of expansion and rearranging  of series, but rather boring ! One have to put Eq.$(2)$ into Eq.$(1)$ and rearrange the terms in decreasing order of the powers of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to give another answer. Recall from wikipedia and the most common definition of asymptotic line, to find an asymptotic line of $f(x)$ as $x\to\infty$, we need to compute

(1) $a=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}$

(2) $b=\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x) - ax)$.

Then the asymptotic line would be $y=ax+b$.

-

By implicit function theorem when $x$ is large, $y$ can be written as a function of $x$.  Let's begin with

$x^3 + 3x^2 y - 4y^3 -x + y + 3 = 0.   \qquad(1)      $

Then

$1+ 3\frac{y}{x} - 4(\frac{y}{x})^3 - \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{y}{x}\frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{3}{x^3}=0$

if $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{y}{x}=:a$ exists, then it might be a solution of $1+3a-4a^3=0$.  Moreover, the little consequence $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{y-ax}{x}=0$ is required.

-

Then we may try $x^3 + 3x^2(y-ax+ax) -4(y-ax+ax)^3 - x + (y-ax+ax) + 3 = 0$. After simplifying, we obtain

$3(y-ax) - 4(y-ax) (\frac{y-ax}{x})^2 - 12 a(\frac{y-ax}{x})^2 - 12( y-ax)a^2 - \frac{1}{x} + \frac{y-ax}{x}\frac{1}{x} + \frac{a}{x} + \frac{3}{x^2}=0$. 
Thus

$(y-ax)[3 -4(\frac{y-ax}{x})^2 -12a^2] = 12a(\frac{y-ax}{x})^2 + \frac{1}{x} -\frac{y-ax}{x}\frac{1}{x} - \frac{a}{x} -\frac{3}{x^2}$. Taking limit, we obtain $b(3-12a^2)=0$, where $b=\lim_{x\to\infty} y-ax$, existing.

Answer (score 0):

$$\newcommand{\AFF}{\mathbb{A}}$$
$$\newcommand{\PSP}{\mathbb{P}}$$

Let

$$
f(x,y) = 0
$$

be an affine plane curve in $\AFF^2_k$. How can one find all possible asymptotic lines $a x + b y + c = 0$?

Answer: One embeds $\AFF^2_k$ into $\PSP^2_k$ with the coordinates $(X:Y:Z)$ and computes the intersections of $f(x,y) = 0$ with the infinite line $Z = 0$. Therefore one puts

$$
Z^d f(X/Z, Y/Z) = g(X,Y,Z) = 0
$$

with $d$ chosen such, that $Z$ does not divide the polynomial $g(X,Y,Z)$.

From $g(X,Y,0) = 0$ one gets a list of intersection points $(X_i: Y_i: 0)$. We choose one of it, which we write wlog as $P = (1 : y_0 : 0)$.

So we assume, that $X = 1$ and compute the affine representation of $f(x,y) = 0$ in the patch $X = 1$, that is $g(1, Y/X, Z/X) = 0$ as $p(u, v) = 0$ with $u=Y/X$ und $v = Z/X$.

It is then $u = y_0, v = 0$ the intersection point $P$ from above. We put $u' = u - y_0$ and get $P = (u' = 0, v = 0)$. Therefore

$$
h(u',v) = p(u' + y_0, v) = h_m(u',v) + \cdots + h_d(u',v)
$$

with $h_\nu$ homogeneus of degree $\nu$ and $d > 0$. We choose a linear factor $l = a u' + b v = 0$ of $h_d$ and transform back

$$
l = a \,(u - y_0) + b \, v = a \, (Y/X - y_0) + b \, (Z/X).
$$

Projectively this is

$$
l = a Y - y_0 X + b Z
$$

and so in the affine patch $Z = 1$ the sought after equation for the asymptotic line is

$$
l = a y - y_0 x + b = 0
$$

Example: Let

$$
f(x,y) = x^3 + y^3 - 3 a \, x y = 0
$$

be "Folium Cartesii".

We have

$$
g(X,Y,Z) = X^3 + Y^3 - 3 a X Y Z = 0.
$$

From $Z= 0$ follows $P=(1:-1:0)$, therefore $y_0 = -1$.

Further we have $p(u,v) = g(1,u,v) = 1 + u^3 - 3 a u v$ and therefore with $u' = u + 1$ we get for $h$

$$
h(u',v) = p(u' - 1, v) = u'^3 - 3 u'^2 + 3 u' - 3 a (u' - 1) v = u'^3 - 3 u'^2 - 3a u' v + 3 u' + 3 a v.
$$

So it is $h_1(u',v) = 3 (u' + a v)$ and $l = u' + a v = u + 1 + a v = Y/X + 1 + a Z/X = 0$, and therefore finally

$$
l = y + x + a = 0.
$$

Finally your example, calculated with maple

[image]

[image]